# How to use OSM for offline map for application in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openstreetmap

I want to develop an application in C# which is having one offline map and I want to plot some markers on that. Is it possible to to use OSM for offline map with C# or ASP.NET? If it is possible, then how?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the OSM data using http://download.geofabrik.de/index.html. One of the most common format used by Applications is Shapefile which is ESRI standard. You can download the data in Shapefile Format. From there you have various avenues of using it in the .Net application. [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) is one of the open source project which supports shapefiles. That will be an offline map application, since your application will hold the data. [DotSpatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/) is anohter open source project, which you can look into.

For ASP.Net application and for it to be an offline map, you have to devise some kind of caching approach. You would also need your own server to rendering map tiles. So that the client can have the map data at his/her end. Instead of having your own server I would suggest you to look into [OSM Map API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) and use that in your web application.

Comment: The cloudmade link above is dead. Here's an alternative: [http://download.geofabrik.de/index.html](http://download.geofabrik.de/index.html)

Comment: @pogosama, thanks for pointing that out. Feel free to edit it next time. Thanks :)

Comment: the SharpMap is very bad choice ,i spent countless hours searching for ways to render in desktop app with no luck :'( if there is another please comment thanks

Comment: @sdx11, surprised that you couldn't get it working, look for DotSpatial as well.

Comment: @Habib, i found a dead end , what i tried so far is country *.osm.pbf copy and tried all solution for c# to create offline map with no luck , now i am using nodejs still searching

Comment: @Habib, i haven't tried DotSpatial but from reading documentation it doesn't support offline *.osm.pbf :'(